# Why is Kotlin much faster than Java at interpreting Brainfuck?

Tags: java, kotlin, benchmarking, jvm-hotspot, brainfuck

In this [Brainfuck v2.0 benchmark](https://github.com/kostya/benchmarks), the [Java version](https://github.com/kostya/benchmarks/blob/master/brainfuck2/bf.java) seems to be equivalent to the [Kotlin version](https://github.com/kostya/benchmarks/blob/master/brainfuck2/bf2.kt), as far as I can tell.

However, it runs twice slower and uses much more memory. Why is that?

I would expect them to have very similar memory and speed characteristics, since both run on the JVM.

Comment: Note that they're using a *fairly* naive benchmark, which isn't a good idea for Java. They have a minor warming procedure, but that doesn't necessarily warm it properly. Ideally, at the very least, it would run the actual code being timed several times instead of some other arbitrary code. The Kotlin version may be more open to JIT optimizations, and the naïve benchmarking being used isn't accounting for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disclaimer: the Kotlin benchmark code is the result of my contribution.

If you compare Java and Kotlin versions of the code you'll notice that they are actually different. Each one uses an idiomatic approach of the corresponding programming language to encode operations.

- Java version uses `enum OpT` combined with `class Op`. To run the brainfuck code it uses an idiomatic Java `switch (op.op)` on enum to select what to do.
- Kotlin version uses `sealed class Op` and an idiomatic Kotlin `when (op)` on type of the operation that exploits Kotlin's flow-sensitive typing (aka smart-cast) to get nice and readable code.

It turns out that idiomatic Kotlin code executes faster on JVM (for no particularly good reason). You can rewrite Java code using the same approach as in Kotlin and you'll get the same performance, however such Java code would look ugly in Java and could not be considered an idiomatic implementation in Java.

Comment: Excellent, but have you tried addressing @Carcigenicate 's concerns about the benchmarking itself?

Comment: I don't think it would have been appropriate to change the nature of the benchmark. It looked to me like the purpose of this benchmark was to compare idomatic and naitve implementations of this particular task in various languages, so I contributed an idiomatic Kotlin one. Personally, I would not recommend to use the results of such a benchmark for any professional purpose. However, it is a fun toy. I, for one, enjoy toying with problems like this one.

Comment: I think his concern is not whether the code is idiomatic or not, but that the benchmark is too short (in time) and it's unclear how much of it gets JIT'ed and whether the JIT compilation itself is an appreciable part of the runtime.